# Use Riesz representation theorem to express $L^1$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

I know $\|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} = \sup_{\|g\|_\infty \leq 1} \int fg$. Is it also true that $\|f\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} = \sup_{g\in \mathcal{S},\|g\|_\infty \leq 1} \int fg$ ? Why or why not?

Here $\mathcal{S}$ denotes the class of Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What is $\mathcal S$?

Comment: $\mathcal{S}$ denotes the class of Schwarz functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Confusing to mention Riesz representation theorem, your result is not directly related to it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I have been wondering that what should I call this fact that the $L^p$ norm of a function is equal to the supremum of its pairing with unit $L^{p'}$ norm functions

Comment: I think the proof is quite the same as "$C^0\cap L^1$ is dense in $L^1$" (which indeed implies your result). Needs to go back to the definition of $L^1$, approximating by simple functions, and use the definition of the Lebesgue sigma algebra, to show that the shift operator is continuous, so we can introduce a convolution.

Comment: Otherwise I have a Fourier transform proof, approximating $f$ by $f 1_{|f|< T}$ to make it $L^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain more about this Fourier transform proof?